# FORTRAN Read() issue

Tags: fortran, readline, gfortran

Hey so I am trying to learn Fortran basics so that I can use it for a basic physics project. I am having trouble with getting input properly. My code is:

```
program main
  write(*, *) "Enter n:"
  read(*, *) n
  print *, "Number is ", n
end program main
```

It is quite simple. Except that when I compile and run it, nothing happens until I enter the input in which it looks like this

```
gfortran num.f90 -o num
./num
(nothing happens until I type) 3
Enter n:
Number is:    3
```

Is there a problem with my memory allocation? Or could it be my compiler? I honestly have no clue.

Comment: That should work.  What operating system and terminal program are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your program is fine, on my machine it prints the `Enter n:` before reading the variable. If you do not see the message until you enter a value (and hit Enter), it could have to do with the buffering of your command window you use. For checking this, you could just open an xterminal (type `xterm` in your command window), and run the program there.